# Half Orc Rogue sneak attack calculation

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue, half-orc

As a half-orc Fighter, I multi classed to rogue. At first rogue level with a rapier and shield, when applying the Savage Attack feature of a half orc, should do additional damage.

Normal damage

```
1d8 + mod and 1d6
```

Critical damage

```
3d8 + mod and 3d6
```

Is this correct?

What if my half-orc advances his rogue levels to 5?

Normal damage

```
1d8 + mod and 3d6
```

Critical damage

```
3d8 + mod and 9d6
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Fighter multi class to rogue that's why I can equip shield

Comment: I edited that multi class in. (You could also have just left out any reference to the shield, but at least we are addressing the F/R multiclass in the case you are asking about).

Answer (score 40):

No, that's not correct. Half-Orcs get the following ability:

> ***Savage
>   Attacks.***
>   When
>   you
>   score
>   a
>   critical
>   hit
>   with
>   a
>   melee
>   weapon
>   attack,
>   you
>   can
>   roll
>   one
>   of
>   the
>   weapon’s
>   damage
>   dice
>   one
>   additional
>   time
>   and
>   add
>   it
>   to
>   the
>   extra
>   damage
>   of
>   the
>   critical
>   hit.

As it says, when you get a crit, you get to roll one of the weapon's damage dice an extra time. So the first part of your calculation, the 3d8 damage your rapier will deal with a crit, is correct. However, Sneak Attack isn't part of the weapon's damage dice, it's extra damage that is added to the damage of the attack. Therefore, it's unaffected by Savage Attacks.

So your calculations should look like:

\begin{array}{c}
\text{Level} & \text{Normal damage} & \text{Critical damage} \\ \hline
1 & 1d8 + mod + 1d6 & 3d8 + mod + 2d6  \\
5 & 1d8 + mod + 3d6 & 3d8 + mod + 6d6  \\
\end{array}

Comment: Miniman, have you made a mistake? The rule is "...you can roll **one of the weapon’s damage dice** one additional time...", but you have suggested rolling *two* of the weapon's damage dice one additional time (i.e. one additional d8, and one additional d6).

Comment: nope, Miniman has it right.  Normal damage is 1d8+mod+1d6.  Crit for anyone but an orc is 2d8+mod+2d6.  Orc lets you tack on one additional d8, for a total of 3d8+mod+2d6.

Comment: @Shem Great, thank you. Can you please *explain how*, that extra 1d6 comes from a level 1 crit? I am still not seeing where "you can roll **one** of the weapon’s damage dice one additional time" turns into 1d8 + 1d6, because that looks like two additional dice, not one. I'd like to be enlightened please. :)

Comment: @lexible Before users edited it out of the question, the whole point of this question is Sneak Attack.

Comment: @lexible, sneak attack is doubled when you crit, just like the weapon dice.  If this was just an orc fighter, we would have 1d8+mod for a normal attack and 3d8+mod for a crit.  But the question includes rogues sneak attack, so the base damage is 1d8+1d6+mod, and the crit is 3d8+2d6+mod because the orc's "Savage Attacks" feature only gives you one additional die, regardless of the number of dice your weapon normally rolls.  One of the d8's comes from the orc feature, and one of the d8's and one of the d6's come from the crit.

Comment: Where did the extra attack (d6) sneak come from if not from weapon damage?

Comment: @RichieKing It came from Sneak Attack: "Once per turn, you can deal an extra 1d6 damage to one creature you hit with an attack if you have advantage on the attack roll." It's extra damage you add to the attack, not part of the weapon's damage dice.